# Screwed up LaTeX when presenting edited posts for approval

Tags: support, mathjax, editing

In about one of every 4 cases when I am asked to approve an edit, the comparison page that shows the suggested edits suffers from incorrect rendering of LaTeX, which often makes both the original and the edited version next to unreadable. Sometimes, when the edit is very minor, I still can figure out what is suggested, but when the edit requires more attention, I just press the "skip" button.

1) Does anybody else have similar experience?

2) What can be done about it?

Comment: Can you please describe more precisely the rendering problems you have come across? I have noticed that the edit revisions (both for suggested edits and in the revision history for posts) sometimes render as if a few dollar signs are missing. This causes parts of the text to render as mathjax, in the characteristic italic math font and without any spaces. Other times, the preview of edit revisions simply ignores the dollar signs and shows the code (surrounded by dollar signs) instead of rendering it as mathjax.

Comment: Yes, a few ignored dollar signs would cause the havoc I see and some dollar signs are visible too. Whether that's the only problem, I cannot tell. @Martin Sleziak I guess the post you quoted describes the same problem. The mods can close or merge, if they want. :)